# How to enable cookies in behat to perform a login functional test?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, behat

I am trying to test a valid login with a `SonataUserBundle` login form and in a `behat` `feature`, i'd like to check if user is redirected on the `login_check` but it seems never working due to cookies problem.

My question is simple, how to perform a valid functional test with `behat` to check if an user is logged to a `Symfony2` application?

I have this configuration in my `behat.yml` file:

```
default:
    formatters:
        pretty: true
    autoload:
        '': %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
    suites:
        test_suite:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: MyBundle
            contexts:
                - Acme\MyBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext:
                    session:   '@session'
                    output_path: build/behat/output
                    screen_shot_path: build/behat/screenshot
            mink_javascript_session: selenium2
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://<internalURL>/web/app_test.php
            sessions:
                goutte: # fast, CLI, browser, no javascript support
                    goutte: ~
                selenium2: # fast, CLI, opens up a browser
                    selenium2: ~
                symfony2: # bleeding fast, CLI, no browser
                    symfony2: ~
```

---

```
Scenario: Clicking on the submit button with good credentials
    When I fill in "_username" with "mylogin"
    And I fill in "_password" with "mypassword"
    Then I press "Login"
    And print last response
    Then I should be on "/login_check"
```

When I do a `And print last response` in my `behat` feature config file, I have this error:

> Your session has timed
>   out, or you have disabled cookies.

The result of the feature:

```
Then I should be on "/login_check"
      Current page is "/<internalURL>/app_test.php/login",
 but "/<internalURL>/app_test.php/login_check" expected.
```

(Behat\Mink\Exception\ExpectationException)

Comment: Your first steps are filling in a form, while you haven't visited a page yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test this behavior you can create this method :

```
/**
 * @When I restart the browser
 */
public function restartBrowser()
{
    $rememberMe = $this->getSession()->getCookie('REMEMBER_ME');
    $this->getSession()->restart();
    $this->visitPath('/');
    $this->getSession()->setCookie('REMEMBER_ME', $rememberMe);
}
```

Please note that the cookie can be prefix by something like the name of your application if you have the **framework.session.name** set.
So REMEMBER_ME can be YOURAPP_REMEMBER_ME

So here an exemple of usage :

```
    Scenario: I can remember my login in my browser
        Given I fill in "_username" with "username"
        And I fill in "_password" with "password"
        And I check "Remember me?"
        And I press "Login"
        Then I should be on my account homepage
        When I restart the browser
        And I go to "/"
        And I should see 1 "body.logged-in" elements
```

Hope it's useful.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you, your example help me improve my tests!